# How to detect the language of a string?

Tags: c#, language-detection

What's the best way to detect the language of a string?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If the context of your code have internet access, you can try to use the Google API for language detection.
http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/

```
var text = "¿Dónde está el baño?";
google.language.detect(text, function(result) {
  if (!result.error) {
    var language = 'unknown';
    for (l in google.language.Languages) {
      if (google.language.Languages[l] == result.language) {
        language = l;
        break;
      }
    }
    var container = document.getElementById("detection");
    container.innerHTML = text + " is: " + language + "";
  }
});
```

And, since you are using c#, take a look at [this article](http://www.esotericdelights.com/post/2008/11/Calling-Google-Ajax-Language-API-for-Translation-and-Language-Detection-from-C.aspx) on how to call the API from c#.

UPDATE:
That c# link is gone, here's a cached copy of the core of it:

```
string s = TextBoxTranslateEnglishToHebrew.Text;
string key = "YOUR GOOGLE AJAX API KEY";
GoogleLangaugeDetector detector =
   new GoogleLangaugeDetector(s, VERSION.ONE_POINT_ZERO, key);

GoogleTranslator gTranslator = new GoogleTranslator(s, VERSION.ONE_POINT_ZERO,
   detector.LanguageDetected.Equals("iw") ? LANGUAGE.HEBREW : LANGUAGE.ENGLISH,
   detector.LanguageDetected.Equals("iw") ? LANGUAGE.ENGLISH : LANGUAGE.HEBREW,
   key);

TextBoxTranslation.Text = gTranslator.Translation;
```

---

Basically, you need to create a URI and send it to Google that looks like:

> http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?v=1.0&q=hello%20worled&langpair=en%7ciw&key=your_google_api_key_goes_here

This tells the API that you want to translate "hello world" from English to Hebrew, to which Google's JSON response would look like:

```
{"responseData": {"translatedText":"שלום העולם"}, "responseDetails": null, "responseStatus": 200}
```

I chose to make a base class that represents a typical Google JSON response:

```
[Serializable]
public class JSONResponse
{
   public string responseDetails = null;
   public string responseStatus = null;
}
```

Then, a Translation object that inherits from this class:

```
[Serializable]
public class Translation: JSONResponse
{
   public TranslationResponseData responseData = 
    new TranslationResponseData();
}
```

This Translation class has a TranslationResponseData object that looks like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class TranslationResponseData
{
   public string translatedText;
}
```

Finally, we can make the GoogleTranslator class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;

namespace GoogleTranslationAPI
{

   public class GoogleTranslator
   {
      private string _q = "";
      private string _v = "";
      private string _key = "";
      private string _langPair = "";
      private string _requestUrl = "";
      private string _translation = "";

      public GoogleTranslator(string queryTerm, VERSION version, LANGUAGE languageFrom,
         LANGUAGE languageTo, string key)
      {
         _q = HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(queryTerm);
         _v = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(EnumStringUtil.GetStringValue(version));
         _langPair =
            HttpUtility.UrlEncode(EnumStringUtil.GetStringValue(languageFrom) +
            "|" + EnumStringUtil.GetStringValue(languageTo));
         _key = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key);

         string encodedRequestUrlFragment =
            string.Format("?v={0}&q={1}&langpair={2}&key={3}",
            _v, _q, _langPair, _key);

         _requestUrl = EnumStringUtil.GetStringValue(BASEURL.TRANSLATE) + encodedRequestUrlFragment;

         GetTranslation();
      }

      public string Translation
      {
         get { return _translation; }
         private set { _translation = value; }
      }

      private void GetTranslation()
      {
         try
         {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(_requestUrl);
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string json = reader.ReadLine();
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json)))
            {
               DataContractJsonSerializer ser =
                  new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Translation));
               Translation translation = ser.ReadObject(ms) as Translation;

               _translation = translation.responseData.translatedText;
            }
         }
         catch (Exception) { }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: True, and I used this too.  But they are pulling support for it's use.

Comment: It seems, that this functionality currently is a part of Google Translate API and offered as a paid service. https://developers.google.com/translate/v2/pricing

Answer (score 26):

*Fast answer:* [**NTextCat**](https://github.com/ivanakcheurov/ntextcat) ([NuGet](http://www.nuget.org/packages/NTextCat/), [Online Demo](http://ivanakcheurov.github.io/ntextcat/))

*Long answer:*

Currently the best way seems to use classifiers **trained** to classify piece of text into one (or more) of languages from predefined set.

There is a Perl tool called [TextCat](http://odur.let.rug.nl/~vannoord/TextCat/). It has language models for 74 most popular languages. There is a huge number of ports of this tool into different programming languages.

There were no ports in .Net. So I have written one: [**NTextCat** on GitHub](https://github.com/ivanakcheurov/ntextcat).

It is **pure .NET Framework** DLL + command line interface to it. By default, it uses a profile of 14 languages.

Any feedback is very appreciated! 
New ideas and feature requests are welcomed too :)

Alternative is to use numerous online services (e.g. one from Google mentioned, detectlanguage.com, langid.net, etc.).

Comment: Awesome work Ivan. I just browsed through your OSS code on Codeplex. I'd be willing to help you with this project if you need it.

Comment: What license does your library use?  I don't see it specified in Github or in the README.

Comment: Please find the NTextcat implementation with demo application and source code here: https://codecanyon.net/item/language-detect/23356008?ref=intelliwins

Answer (score 8):

A statistical approach using digraphs or trigraphs is a very good indicator. For example, here are the most common digraphs in English in order: http://www.letterfrequency.org/#digraph-frequency (one can find better or more complete lists). This method may have a better success rate than word analysis for short snippets of text because there are more digraphs in text than there are complete words.

Answer (score 6):

Make a statistical analyses of the string: Split the string into words. Get a dictionary for every language you want to test for. And then find the language that has the highest word count.

In C# every string in memory will be unicode, and is not encoded. Also in text files the encoding is not stored. (Sometimes only an indication of 8-bit or 16-bit).

If you want to make a distinction between two languages, you might find some simple tricks. For example if you want to recognize English from Dutch, the string that contains the "y" is mostly  English. (Unreliable but fast).

Comment: Are you saying there's no "y" in Dutch? I can give you 100 Dutch words with a "y" straight away.

Comment: This might be suitable for a beginning programming class, but is far from a real solution to the problem.

Comment: But there is no 100% reliable language detection. If you want a fast distinction, unreliable between Dutch and English, counting the y's will perform very nice (that's what the "mostly" means).

Answer (score 6):

If you mean the natural (ie human) language, this is in general a Hard Problem. What language is "server" - English or Turkish? What language is "chat" - English or French? What language is "uno" - Italian or Spanish (or Latin!) ?

Without paying attention to context, and doing some hard **natural language processing** (<----- this is the phrase to google for) you haven't got a chance.

You might enjoy a look at [Frengly](http://www.frengly.com) - it's a nice UI onto the Google Translate service which attempts to guess the language of the input text...

Answer (score 4):

**CLD3 (Compact Language Detector v3)** library from Google's Chromium browser

You could wrap the [CLD3 library](https://github.com/google/cld3), which is written in C++.

Comment: There are also [Python bindings](https://github.com/Elizafox/cld3) (`pip install cld3` but you might need Cython) and [Ruby bindings](https://github.com/akihikodaki/cld3-ruby)

Comment: There's also an official Python binding now, `pip install gcld3`

Answer (score 3):

We can use `Regex.IsMatch(text, "[\\uxxxx-\\uxxxx]+")` to detect an specific language. Here xxxx is the 4 digit Unicode id of a character.
To detect Arabic:

```
bool isArabic = Regex.IsMatch(yourtext, @"[\u0600-\u06FF]+")
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use the [C# package for language identification](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/5a84b263-41d6-4ce1-a186-8e3f76efe2e5/) from Microsoft Research:

> This package implements several algorithms for language
>   identification, and includes two sets of pre-compiled language
>   profiles. One set covers 52 languages and was trained on Wikipedia
>   (i.e. a well-written corpus); the other covers 26 languages and was
>   constructed from Twitter (i.e. a highly colloquial corpus). The
>   language identifiers are packaged up as a C# library, and be easily
>   embedded into other C# projects.

Download the package from the above link.

Comment: Could you explain how can I add this package to my existing C# windows form application?

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to use '[Translator Text API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/translator-info-overview)' which is

> ... part of the Azure Cognitive Services API collection of machine
>   learning and AI algorithms in the cloud, and is readily consumable in
>   your development projects

Here's [a quickstart guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/quickstart-csharp-detect) on how to detect language from text using this API