# How to change Color Dialog language

Tags: c#, winforms, colordialog

I write a word processor in C#, but not in English.
I want to use the Color Dialog, but I want to change the words in Color Dialog to another language, how can I do it?

Comment: I think setting `Culture` property of CurrentUI Thread should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question but in case anyone else ever needs an answer to this, you can use a few different winapi calls to change the text of the color dialog. Here is some sample C# code to demonstrate.

**NOTE:** Since the 'Basic colors:' and 'Custom colors:' labels are referenced by the same control ID, a fairly indirect method of finding the handle to the 'Custom colors:' label has been implemented. If all of the control ID's on the color dialog were unique then the 'Custom colors:' label text could be set as easily as the rest of the controls.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Open the color dialog before the form actually loads

            ColorDialogEx oColorDialog = new ColorDialogEx(this.CreateGraphics());

            oColorDialog.FullOpen = true;
            oColorDialog.ShowDialog();
        }
    }

    public class ColorDialogEx : ColorDialog
    {
        private const Int32 WM_INITDIALOG = 0x0110; // Windows Message Constant
        private Graphics oGraphics;
        private const uint GW_HWNDLAST = 1;
        private const uint GW_HWNDPREV = 3;

        private string sColorPickerText = "1-Color Picker";
        private string sBasicColorsText = "2-Basic colors:";
        private string sDefineCustomColorsButtonText = "3-Define Custom Colors >>";
        private string sOKButtonText = "4-OK";
        private string sCancelButtonText = "5-Cancel";
        private string sAddToCustomColorsButtonText = "6-Add to Custom Colors";
        private string sColorText = "7-Color";
        private string sSolidText = "|8-Solid";
        private string sHueText = "9-Hue:";
        private string sSatText = "10-Sat:";
        private string sLumText = "11-Lum:";
        private string sRedText = "12-Red:";
        private string sGreenText = "13-Green:";
        private string sBlueText = "14-Blue:";
        private string sCustomColorsText = "15-Custom colors:";

        // WinAPI definitions

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool SetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, string text);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern long GetWindowRect(int hWnd, ref Rectangle lpRect);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool GetTitleBarInfo(IntPtr hwnd, ref TITLEBARINFO pti);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetDlgItem(IntPtr hDlg, int nIDDlgItem);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint uCmd);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, System.Text.StringBuilder lpClassName, int nMaxCount);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        struct TITLEBARINFO
        {
            public const int CCHILDREN_TITLEBAR = 5;
            public uint cbSize;
            public RECT rcTitleBar;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = CCHILDREN_TITLEBAR + 1)]
            public uint[] rgstate;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;

            public RECT(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
            {
                Left = left;
                Top = top;
                Right = right;
                Bottom = bottom;
            }

            public RECT(System.Drawing.Rectangle r) : this(r.Left, r.Top, r.Right, r.Bottom) { }

            public int X
            {
                get { return Left; }
                set { Right -= (Left - value); Left = value; }
            }

            public int Y
            {
                get { return Top; }
                set { Bottom -= (Top - value); Top = value; }
            }

            public int Height
            {
                get { return Bottom - Top; }
                set { Bottom = value + Top; }
            }

            public int Width
            {
                get { return Right - Left; }
                set { Right = value + Left; }
            }

            public System.Drawing.Point Location
            {
                get { return new System.Drawing.Point(Left, Top); }
                set { X = value.X; Y = value.Y; }
            }

            public System.Drawing.Size Size
            {
                get { return new System.Drawing.Size(Width, Height); }
                set { Width = value.Width; Height = value.Height; }
            }

            public static implicit operator System.Drawing.Rectangle(RECT r)
            {
                return new System.Drawing.Rectangle(r.Left, r.Top, r.Width, r.Height);
            }

            public static implicit operator RECT(System.Drawing.Rectangle r)
            {
                return new RECT(r);
            }

            public static bool operator ==(RECT r1, RECT r2)
            {
                return r1.Equals(r2);
            }

            public static bool operator !=(RECT r1, RECT r2)
            {
                return !r1.Equals(r2);
            }

            public bool Equals(RECT r)
            {
                return r.Left == Left && r.Top == Top && r.Right == Right && r.Bottom == Bottom;
            }

            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                if (obj is RECT)
                    return Equals((RECT)obj);
                else if (obj is System.Drawing.Rectangle)
                    return Equals(new RECT((System.Drawing.Rectangle)obj));
                return false;
            }

            public override int GetHashCode()
            {
                return ((System.Drawing.Rectangle)this).GetHashCode();
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{{Left={0},Top={1},Right={2},Bottom={3}}}", Left, Top, Right, Bottom);
            }
        }

        public ColorDialogEx(Graphics g)
        {
            oGraphics = g;
        }

        protected override IntPtr HookProc(IntPtr nColorDialogHandle, int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
        {
            IntPtr returnValue = base.HookProc(nColorDialogHandle, msg, wparam, lparam);

            if (msg == WM_INITDIALOG)
            {
                IntPtr[] oStaticHandleArray = new IntPtr[9];

                // Change the window title

                SetWindowText(nColorDialogHandle, sColorPickerText);

                // Get titlebar info for calculations later

                TITLEBARINFO oTITLEBARINFO = new TITLEBARINFO();
                oTITLEBARINFO.cbSize = (uint)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(oTITLEBARINFO);
                GetTitleBarInfo(nColorDialogHandle, ref oTITLEBARINFO);

                // Change the text of the "Basic colors:" label

                oStaticHandleArray[0] = GetDlgItem(nColorDialogHandle, 0xFFFF);

                SetWindowText(oStaticHandleArray[0], sBasicColorsText);

                // Change the text of the "Define Custom Colors >>" button

                SetWindowText(GetDlgItem(nColorDialogHandle, 0x2CF), sDefineCustomColorsButtonText);

                // Save the "OK" button size and new width

                Rectangle oOKButtonRect = new Rectangle();
                int nOKButtonWidth = (int)oGraphics.MeasureString(sOKButtonText, new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8, FontStyle.Regular)).Width + 20;  // +20 accounts for extra +10 padding on either side

                // Find the "OK" Button

                IntPtr nChildHandle = GetDlgItem(nColorDialogHandle, 0x1);

                if (nChildHandle.ToInt32() > 0)
                {
                    // The "OK" button was found
                    // Now save the current size and position

                    GetWindowRect(nChildHandle.ToInt32(), ref oOKButtonRect);

                    // We have to subtract oOKButtonRect.X value from oOKButtonRect.Width to obtain the "real" button width (same thing with subtracting Y value from Height)

                    oOKButtonRect.Width = oOKButtonRect.Width - oOKButtonRect.X;
                    oOKButtonRect.Height = oOKButtonRect.Height - oOKButtonRect.Y;

                    // Resize the "OK" button so that the new text fits properly
                    // NOTE: I cannot be sure 100% if it is correct to use the titlebar to find the position of the button or not but the math works out in all of my tests

                    MoveWindow(nChildHandle, oOKButtonRect.X - oTITLEBARINFO.rcTitleBar.X, oOKButtonRect.Y - oTITLEBARINFO.rcTitleBar.Y - oTITLEBARINFO.rcTitleBar.Height, nOKButtonWidth, oOKButtonRect.Height, true);

                    // Finally, change the button text

                    SetWindowText(nChildHandle, sOKButtonText);
                }

                // Find the "Cancel" Button

                nChildHandle = GetDlgItem(nColorDialogHandle, 0x2);

                if (nChildHandle.ToInt32() > 0)
                {
                    // The "Cancel" button was found
                    // Now get the current size and position

                    Rectangle oCancelButtonRect = new Rectangle();
                    GetWindowRect(nChildHandle.ToInt32(), ref oCancelButtonRect);

                    // We have to subtract oCancelButtonRect.X value from oCancelButtonRect.Width to obtain the "real" button width (same thing with subtracting Y value from Height)

                    oCancelButtonRect.Width = oCancelButtonRect.Width - oCancelButtonRect.X;
                    oCancelButtonRect.Height = oCancelButtonRect.Height - oCancelButtonRect.Y;

                    // Resize the "Cancel" button so that the new text fits properly
                    // NOTE: I cannot be sure 100% if it correct to use the titlebar to find the position of the button or not but the math works out in all of my tests

                    MoveWindow(nChildHandle, oOKButtonRect.X + nOKButtonWidth - oTITLEBARINFO.rcTitleBar.X + 6, oCancelButtonRect.Y - oTITLEBARINFO.rcTitleBar.Y - oTITLEBARINFO.rcTitleBar.Height, (int)oGraphics.MeasureString(sCancelButtonText, new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 8, FontStyle.Regular)).Width + 20, oCancelButtonRect.Height, true);

                    // Finally, change the button text

                    SetWindowText(nChildHandle, sCancelButtonText);
                }

                // Change the text of the "Add to Custom Colors" button

                SetWindowText(GetDlgItem(nColorDialogHandle, 0x2C8), sAddToCustomColorsButtonText);

                // Change the text of the "Color" label text

                oStaticHandleArray[1] = GetDlgItem(nColorDialogHandle, 0x2DA);

                SetWindowText(oStaticHandleArray[1], sColorText);

                // Change the text of the "Solid" label text

                oStaticHandleArray[2] = GetDlgItem(nColorDialogHandle, 0x2DB);

                SetWindowText(oStaticHandleArray[2], sSolidText);

                // Change the text of the "Hue:" label

                oStaticHandleArray[3] = GetDlgItem(nColorDialogHandle, 0x2D3);

                SetWindowText(oStaticHandleArray[3], sHueText);

                // Change the text of the "Sat:" label

                oStaticHandleArray[4] = GetDlgItem(nColorDialogHandle, 0x2D4);

                SetWindowText(oStaticHandleArray[4], sSatText);

                // Change the text of the "Lum:" label

                oStaticHandleArray[5] = GetDlgItem(nColorDialogHandle, 0x2D5);

                SetWindowText(oStaticHandleArray[5], sLumText);

                // Change the text of the "Red:" label

                oStaticHandleArray[6] = GetDlgItem(nColorDialogHandle, 0x2D6);

                SetWindowText(oStaticHandleArray[6], sRedText);

                // Change the text of the "Green:" label

                oStaticHandleArray[7] = GetDlgItem(nColorDialogHandle, 0x2D7);

                SetWindowText(oStaticHandleArray[7], sGreenText);

                // Change the text of the "Blue:" label

                oStaticHandleArray[8] = GetDlgItem(nColorDialogHandle, 0x2D8);

                SetWindowText(oStaticHandleArray[8], sBlueText);

                // Change the text of the "Custom Colors:" label

                SetCustomColorsText(nColorDialogHandle, oStaticHandleArray);
            }

            return returnValue;
        }

        private static string GetClassName(IntPtr nHandle)
        {
            // Create the stringbuilder object that is used to get the window class name from the GetClassName win api function

            System.Text.StringBuilder sClassName = new System.Text.StringBuilder(100);
            GetClassName(nHandle, sClassName, sClassName.Capacity);
            return sClassName.ToString();
        }

        private static string GetWindowText(IntPtr nHandle)
        {
            // Create the stringbuilder object that is used to get the window text from the GetWindowText win api function

            System.Text.StringBuilder sWindowText = new System.Text.StringBuilder(100);
            GetWindowText(nHandle, sWindowText, sWindowText.Capacity);
            return sWindowText.ToString();
        }

        private void SetCustomColorsText(IntPtr nHandle, IntPtr[] oStaticHandleArray)
        {
            // Find the last control based on the handle to the main window

            IntPtr nWorkingHandle = GetWindow(FindWindowEx(nHandle, IntPtr.Zero, null, null), GW_HWNDLAST);
            bool bFound = false;

            do
            {
                // Look only for "Static" controls that we have not already changed

                if (GetClassName(nWorkingHandle) == "Static" && oStaticHandleArray.Contains(nWorkingHandle) == false)
                {
                    // Found a "Static" control
                    // Check to see if it is the one we are looking for

                    string sControlText = GetWindowText(nWorkingHandle);

                    if (sControlText != "")
                    {
                        // Found the "Custom Colors:" label
                        // Change the text of the "Custom Colors:" label

                        SetWindowText(nWorkingHandle, sCustomColorsText);
                        bFound = true;
                    }
                }

                // Working backwards we look for the previous control

                nWorkingHandle = GetWindow(nWorkingHandle, GW_HWNDPREV);

                // Jump out of the loop when the working handle doesn't find anymore controls

                if (nWorkingHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
                    break;
            } while (bFound == false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The dialog will be in the language of the OS the user installed.

There is no way to manually define the language, of localizations for it.

If you still would want it, you would have to build one yourself, or use components like the Telerik components and localize it yourself. Those components aren't ceeap though..

Comment: But how can I build myself, it has the WinAPI interface? or something like that

Answer (score 0):

A language detector may be useful. see:

- [Detect a written text's language](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43198/Detect-a-written-text-s-language)
- [Return the language of a given string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192768/return-the-language-of-a-given-string/1192802#1192802)

[Avalon editor](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42490/Using-AvalonEdit-WPF-Text-Editor) is a reliable and open-source project can help you for this issue too.