# How do I know whether a character to a given language? In Unicode string

Tags: c#, string, unicode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Return the language of a given string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192768/return-the-language-of-a-given-string)

The task is to sort the list of strings. With priority to a specific language.
Strings can be written in different languages.
Such as Chinese, English, Russian.
And I need to first take all the Chinese, and then the rest.

To do this, I want to know what country (language) belongs to a particular character in a string. ( 
For example on the first letter of)

Are there any classes or methods?

Comment: Try this link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192768/return-the-language-of-a-given-string/1192802#1192802

Comment: I voted to close based on D J's link because it sounds like two different problems. One is to identify the language, which is the link, and the other is to sort by what is identified, which is pretty simple.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I thought about the method that suggested Baboon

And the study of the class System.Text.UnicodeEncoding
makes me think otherwise.
Too many features to unicode, to do a simple cast.

But it would be a nice solution use of library functions.

Comment: Google API is poor solution, i need detect lang only C# code without network

Answer (score 5):

If we're talking alphabets, then you can simply check the int representation of a char by casting it:

```
int unicodeValue = (int)myString[0];
```

Then using a table such as [this one](http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html) you check if it's within the limit of a language.
For example, `丐` is `19984`, which is `4E10` in hexadecimal (`19984.ToString("X")`), making it a *CJK Unified Ideographs*. It looks like this it's the category for chinese characters, but you need to dig around and make sure.

Now if we're talking about determining which language is a particular word from, you need to look into Soundex algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Try this link

[How to detect the language of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192768/return-the-language-of-a-given-string/1192802#1192802)

Code is(Copied)

```
var text = "¿Dónde está el baño?";
google.language.detect(text, function(result) {
if (!result.error) {
var language = 'unknown';
for (l in google.language.Languages) {
  if (google.language.Languages[l] == result.language) {
    language = l;
    break;
  }
}
var container = document.getElementById("detection");
container.innerHTML = text + " is: " + language + "";
}
});
```