# Detect language while reading from textfile automatically

Tags: c#, file-io

I know how to read and write the language if i already know the language..For example here is the code to read and write russian language.

```
    public string FileRead(string filename, String Contents)
    {
        Contents = File.ReadAllText(filename,Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-5"));
        return Contents;
    }
    public void FileWrite(string contents)
    {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("C:\\pathe.txt", contents,Encoding.UTF8);
    }
```

But my problem is that if i don't know the language then how can i detect that particular language automatically and then go to that particular code.(i.e in case of russian language,this code)

Comment: I would say with great difficulty :) Unless the language is defined in the file somehow - anything you write will be a guess at best. Obviously, you can write code to detected Russian; but again not really as it may be Ukrainian, unless you further reduce it to character searching; but then again; you just mightn't have any words with Ukrainian specific characters (just an example).

Comment: I guessed that it wouldn't be that much simple but i still hoped that there would be an easy solution..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I originally posted a link to detecting a language, but the real answer is actually here:

[How to detect the language of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192768/return-the-language-of-a-given-string/1192802#1192802)

hope this helps mate