# MySQL - is it possible to determine the language of text contained in a field?

Tags: mysql

I can see no obvious of way of achieving this but I have a database with a `text` field - it contains text in various languages, for example:

- English
- US English
- Japanese
- Arabic
- German

Is there a way within MySQL to determine the language of the text in the field?

Comment: no. consider `gift`: English: present. German: poison.

Comment: I really don't think that such feature exists. You should retrieve the field from the database and THEN process the string using some logic used to detect the language.

Comment: Not directly from MySQL - see this though : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192768/how-to-detect-the-language-of-a-string

Comment: Thanks @PaulF, really appreciated.  Not sure how I didn't spot that in my search of SO before posting.