# How to Check a input text is Norwegian language or not in c#

Tags: c#

I have to make a c# console application which identify whether the input text is a Norwegian Language or not.from [Here](http://peakfinders.blogspot.in/2014/11/how-to-find-string-to-language.html) I am able to find most of language which I need. I googled so much but not getting any idea for identifying Norwegian language.
there is a question on [staskoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192768/how-to-detect-the-language-of-a-string) but it is for webbase applications not for console application.

Comment: Do you have a list of _all_ Norwegian words?

Comment: Not sure, hence the comment, but you could create a regular expression which contains all the possible Norwegian characters. This obviously leaves out the issue of the input text being actual Norwegian words, but it saves you from having to match each word as well as any NLP processing you would need to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192768/how-to-detect-the-language-of-a-string

Comment: no till now search for the same. thanks

Comment: @NarekArzumanyan Ihad already go through that question i think one of those answers is webbase(google api) and another one is giving 7 different language for a sample text

Comment: @patrickHolfman plz check my above comment